# "SQLite JDBC: inconsistent internal state" when attempting to getColumnCount from ResultSetMetaData

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

As the title would suggest I'm attempting to retrieve a Table Model from a result set of data. I'm still in the process of learning how to use Databases so I'm currently using this code:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class DbUtils {
    public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            Vector columnNames = new Vector();

            // Get the column names
            for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
                columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
            }

            // Get all rows.
            Vector rows = new Vector();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector newRow = new Vector();

                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }

                rows.addElement(newRow);
            }

            return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But pretty much the issue I'm having now is whenever the program reaches the line to retrieve the Column Count it gives me the "Inconsistent Internal State" error. Full list here:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SQLite JDBC: inconsistent internal state
at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkCol(CoreResultSet.java:81)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getColumnCount(JDBC3ResultSet.java:699)
at DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(DbUtils.java:14)
at Window.main(Window.java:170)
```

I've checked out the only other question related to this on stack overflow but got no insight from that one. Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen that "inconsistent internal state" error on calling `getColumnCount` when the `ResultSetMetaData` object is created *after* all of the rows of the `ResultSet` have been retrieved, i.e., `rs.next()` has been called until it returns `false` (and consequently `rs.isAfterLast()` returns `true`).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that this error often arises when `rs.next()` has are no more records to point to in the `ResultSet` `rs`.

I found the error this snippet of code , here the `buildModel` is an object of the class `BuildModel`, both building methods `buildOneTable` and `buildSecondTable` use the `rs.next()`.

```
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        oneTable.setModel(buildModel.buildOneTable(rs));
        twoTable.setModel(buildModel.buildSecondTable(rs));            
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
```

in the code given above, you can see that both tables are built using methods `buildOneTable` and `buildSecondTable` of the class `buildModel` and only one `PreparedStatement` variable `ps` is used. The error arises as the `rs.next()` in `buildOneTable`(inside `buildModel`) has pointed to all records , since a single `ps` is used for building methods they both share the same `next()` pointer ,and now there are no more records to point when building the second table. To resolve this error you can do the following :

1. Repoint the `next()` pointer to the beginning of the `resultSet` `rs` by using `rs.first()`.
2. Or as in my case executing the statement again like :

   ```
       ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
       rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
       presentTable.setModel(buildModel.buildPresentLeaveTable(rs1)); 
       rs1.close();
       rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
       pastTable.setModel(buildModel.buildPastLeaveTable(rs2));
       ps.close();
       rs2.close();
   ```